# Arraylist.clear() deletes content of hashTable

Tags: java, arraylist, hashtable

I have the following code:

```
podmienky.put(key, podmienkyOblast);
podmienkyOblast.clear();
```

`podmienky` is `HashTable<String, ArrayList<String>>` and `podmienkyOblast` is `ArrayList<String>`. If I put `podmienky.get("index").size()` before `podmienkyOblast.clear()` it returns 6 as it should. However if I put `podmienky.get("index").size()` after `podmienkyOblast.clear()` it returns 0. I thought that if I put something to hashtable I actualy add content of it to it. But as I can see it is storing only reference to arrayList. Am I wrong? How should I make this work?

Thanks in forward

Comment: Yes, it just stores the reference -- You should create a copy and save it yourself

Comment: That's how it's supposed to work. What do you mean by "How should I make this work"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put a reference to your `ArrayList` into the `Hashtable`. If you want to add values from your `ArrayList` to the table, you have to iterate over the elements in the list.

```
for(Object element : podmienkyOblast) {
    // TODO generate a key for your value here
    String key = "...";
    podmienky.put(key, element);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java deals with Object reference, if you need to copy the object, you need to consider [cloning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloning_(programming)) (a.k.a deep copy).

Also, Favour **interfaces over implementations**, so use `List` instead of `ArrayList`.